# How to center align two inline images in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, center

My problem today is that on my HTML code, I have two images and I can't find a way to center them both. It should look something like this[image: What I want it to look like]

but I cant get the two images to be aligned in the center and still in the same line (excuse my poor paint skills).

This is what I have so far:
HTML

> This Week's Photo Features
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum alienum percipit eum ne. Vel ne paulo inermis, natum numquam vix ei, ex pri dicit blandit vituperata. Ne vel porro clita, aperiam consetetur referrentur mea et, per falli ornatus adolescens ex. Sea doming comprehensam ad, vim te aeque melius.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum alienum percipit eum ne. Vel ne paulo inermis, natum numquam vix ei, ex pri dicit blandit vituperata. Ne vel porro clita, aperiam consetetur referrentur mea et, per falli ornatus adolescens ex. Sea doming comprehensam ad, vim te aeque melius.

```
    <h1 align="center">Last Week's Photo Features</h1>
    <img src="CaliforniaKelp.jpg"  />
    <img src="RockyMountains.jpg" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum alienum percipit eum ne. Vel ne paulo inermis, natum numquam vix ei, ex pri dicit blandit vituperata. Ne vel porro clita, aperiam consetetur referrentur mea et, per falli ornatus adolescens ex. Sea doming comprehensam ad, vim te aeque melius.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum alienum percipit eum ne. Vel ne paulo inermis, natum numquam vix ei, ex pri dicit blandit vituperata. Ne vel porro clita, aperiam consetetur referrentur mea et, per falli ornatus adolescens ex. Sea doming comprehensam ad, vim te aeque melius.</p>
<body>
```

CSS:

> 

```
    h1:before   {content: url("NikonD100_40x30.jpg")}
    h1:after   {content: url("NikonD100_40x30.jpg")}
    p:nth-of-type(1)::first-letter {font-size:44px;font-weight: bold; color: red; float:left; line-height: 35px; padding-top: 3px; padding-right:3px;}
    p:nth-of-type(1)::first-line {font-weight: bold;}
    p:nth-of-type(2)::first-letter {font-size:44px;font-weight: bold; float:left; line-height: 35px; padding-top: 3px; padding-right:3px;color:black;}
    p:nth-of-type(2)::first-line {font-weight: bold;color:red;}
     p:nth-of-type(3)::first-letter {font-size:44px;font-weight: bold; color: red; float:left; line-height: 35px; padding-top: 3px; padding-right:3px;}
    p:nth-of-type(3)::first-line {font-weight: bold;}
    p:nth-of-type(4)::first-letter {font-size:44px;font-weight: bold; float:left; line-height: 35px; padding-top: 3px; padding-right:3px;color:black;}
    p:nth-of-type(4)::first-line {font-weight: bold;color:red;}
</style>
```

Comment: can you wrap the two images with a single div and then center that div with margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<h1 align="center">Last Week's Photo Features</h1>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<img src="CaliforniaKelp.jpg" style="display:inline-block;"  />
<img src="RockyMountains.jpg" style="display:inline-block;" />
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum alienum percipit eum ne. Vel ne paulo inermis, natum numquam vix ei, ex pri dicit blandit vituperata. Ne vel porro clita, aperiam consetetur referrentur mea et, per falli ornatus adolescens ex. Sea doming comprehensam ad, vim te aeque melius.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum alienum percipit eum ne. Vel ne paulo inermis, natum numquam vix ei, ex pri dicit blandit vituperata. Ne vel porro clita, aperiam consetetur referrentur mea et, per falli ornatus adolescens ex. Sea doming comprehensam ad, vim te aeque melius.</p>
```

As @dboals mentioned;

```
<h1 align="center">Last Week's Photo Features</h1>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<img src="CaliforniaKelp.jpg" style="display:inline-block;"  />
<img src="RockyMountains.jpg" style="display:inline-block;" />
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum alienum percipit eum ne. Vel ne paulo inermis, natum numquam vix ei, ex pri dicit blandit vituperata. Ne vel porro clita, aperiam consetetur referrentur mea et, per falli ornatus adolescens ex. Sea doming comprehensam ad, vim te aeque melius.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum alienum percipit eum ne. Vel ne paulo inermis, natum numquam vix ei, ex pri dicit blandit vituperata. Ne vel porro clita, aperiam consetetur referrentur mea et, per falli ornatus adolescens ex. Sea doming comprehensam ad, vim te aeque melius.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
<h1 align="center">Last Week's Photo Features</h1>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<img src="CaliforniaKelp.jpg" style="display:inline-block;"  />
<img src="RockyMountains.jpg" style="display:inline-block;" />
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum alienum percipit eum ne. Vel ne paulo inermis, natum numquam vix ei, ex pri dicit blandit vituperata. Ne vel porro clita, aperiam consetetur referrentur mea et, per falli ornatus adolescens ex. Sea doming comprehensam ad, vim te aeque melius.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum alienum percipit eum ne. Vel ne paulo inermis, natum numquam vix ei, ex pri dicit blandit vituperata. Ne vel porro clita, aperiam consetetur referrentur mea et, per falli ornatus adolescens ex. Sea doming comprehensam ad, vim te aeque melius.</p>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/urcu02cv/)